# Convert vertex color to a vertex group

Tags: python, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have an object with a vertex color

[image]

and I would like to convert it into a vertex group but I don't know how.
A script solution would be fine as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try geometry nodes?

[image]

[image]

you need a vertex group and a color attribute.

[image]

Comment: a bit more steps how to set it up would be useful for other people with the same problem but I got to work